# html video, streaming video

Tags: html, html5

Можно ли после получения очередного кадра менять некоторые пиксели на нем без использования canvas?

Comment: По моему нельзя. Разве что предварительно при загрузке на сервер можно обработать видео статично для всех или же возможно при использовании flash можно это порешать, но, как я понял это не ваш случай. А чем использование canvas для этого дела не подходит?

Comment: @ragmon он ведь медленный